# Integer and string won't right pad.. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code is below. What ends up happening is it's as if I used leftPadding instead of rightPadding and a string or long integer will run of the screen to the right. What I want is for the string is pad itself on the right and it's length extends to the left..

```
- (void)constructTimeStampLabel {
    CGFloat rightPadding = 250.f;
    CGFloat topPadding = -30.f;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rightPadding,
                              topPadding,
                              floorf(CGRectGetWidth(__informationView.frame)),
                              CGRectGetHeight(__informationView.frame) - topPadding);
    _timeStampLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent on %@", _feedItem.timeStamp];
    _timeStampLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [_timeStampLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [__informationView addSubview:_timeStampLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the alignment to the right.

```
_timeStampLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: That works but now I'm getting this issue where the text sort of vertically centers itself instead of dropping down a line.. see links:
http://imgur.com/wA1Kmzj,XtK6bUt
http://imgur.com/XtK6bUt

Comment: that's a little more complex then. UILabels always vertically align to the middle, you can't set that to align to the top. What I do in that case is use NSString's boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context to get the size the text will take up. then use that size and your fixed origin, and that'll seem like it's top-aligned. See my next comment for code.

Comment: CGRect frame = [_timeStampLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_timeStampLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : _timeStampLabel.font}
                                                      context:nil];
    
    frame.origin = _timeStampLabel.frame.origin;
    _timeStampLabel.frame = frame;